Web workers in React app randomly crash with a canceled chunk.js error
setting
I have a React app (using create-react-app) that utilizes web workers for multithreading. The main worker spawns multiple child workers, up to the number of CPU cores minus one, to perform various tasks in parallel.
The child workers are created in a loop using the following approach:
const childWorker = new Worker(new URL(`./pathToWorker.worker.js`, import.meta.url), { name: `child_worker-${index + 1}` });


the main worker is created in the same way

The pathToWorker.worker.js file looks like this:
import { ChildJobExecutor } from "./childJobExecutor";

const childJobExecutor = new ChildJobExecutor();

onmessage = (message) => childJobExecutor[message.data[0]](...message.data[1]);


ChildJobExecutor implementation is irrelevant since it works most times but when it doesn't it doesn't even initialise

The issue:
When spawning multiple child workers, most of the time everything works fine. However, occasionally (and seemingly at random), one or a few workers crash immediately after they are created. This happens completely at random, sometimes all workers run smoothly, but sometimes a few crash.
Here's what I've observed when workers crash:

I see a canceled status on the chunk.js file corresponding to the number of crashed workers (in Chrome DevTools, Network tab).
The child worker doesn't even reach its constructor before crashing.
In worker.onError, most of the data is missing, and the error message is undefined. On one occasion, I did get a "network changed" error (I was connected via Ethernet at the time).

What i tried so far:

delayed worker creation  with a timeout of 500ms - still happened
updating chrome - still happened

Additional Notes:

I noticed that the ChatGPT service also disconnects often, showing network changed errors, but this issue stopped happening.
i didn't get this behaviour on Firefox
this happens when im connected both to Ethernet and WiFi and on different networks

Environment:

Chrome: 129.0.6668.100
Node: 18.17.0
npm: 10.7.0
react-scripts: "^5.0.0"
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Has anyone experienced similar issues, or could this be related to the random network changes I'm observing? Any insights on how to handle or prevent these crashes would be greatly appreciated.

If it only happens with 2 simultaneous connections, it is most likely a browser bug.  Even more so if it only happens in Chrome (you say Firefox works).

not necessarily 2  simultaneous connections, i try to create 15 workers for instance (on one of my machines) and most times 1-2 workers are crashing, sometimes much more
